# Ember-Data "Error: Assertion Failed: You made a 'findRecord' request for a 'user' with id 'current', but the adapter's response did not have any data"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using Ember 3.17 and trying to set up Ember Data to make a server call using the JSONAPIAdapter, however I keep getting this error:

`Error: Assertion Failed: You made a 'findRecord' request for a 'user' with id 'current', but the adapter's response did not have any data`

Am I doing something wrong with my adapter?

Below find my adapter, route and the expected data for this call (I have a model set up, with one attribute). The only thing that's a little weird is my endpoint is /users/current but current does not match the ID on the object. (However when I do match the ID, which is a valid endpoint, I get the same error)

adapters/application.js

```
import JSONAPIAdapter from '@ember-data/adapter/json-api';
import ENV from 'rendia-tv-web/config/environment';

export default class ApplicationAdapter extends JSONAPIAdapter {
  host = ENV.APP.API_HOST;
  namespace = 'tv/v1';

  headers = {
    'Authorization': <authHeader>,
  };

  ajax = function(url, method, hash) {
    hash.crossDomain = true;
    hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
    return this._super(url, method, hash);
  }
  
}
```

routes/application.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default class ApplicationRoute extends Route {

  @service store;

  async model() {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', 'current');
  }

}
```

expected data

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "12345",
        "type": "users",
        "attributes": {
            "username": "email@email.com",
            "name": "User 1"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "practice": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "practice",
                    "id": "55555"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "type": "practice",
            "id": "55555",
            "attributes": {
                "date_created": "2016-09-23T04:21:38-04:00",
                "name": "Practice Name",
                "expiration_date": "2024-10-23T23:59:59-04:00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not 100%ly sure but I think Ember Data expect the record returned by a request triggered by `findRecord()` to have the ID passed to `findRecord`. I don't think the usage of a pseudo-ID like `"current"`, which then resolves to an actual ID `"12345"` is supported.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure @jelhan is right on this one. When you do `findRecord('user', 'current')` Ember Data is going to expect a response for a model with ID `'current'`. Is this alias-style request a JSON API feature? The solution is probably to make a plain XHR request to your endpoint and then [push](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.19/classes/Store/methods/push?anchor=push) the result into the store.

Comment: JSON:API specification does not have official support for these kind of aliases. But the specification is agnostic about the URL design in general. So it doesn't know that some part of the URL encodes the ID used to lookup a resource. That means it also doesn't permit doing this. This seems to be a limitation of the client-side library (ember-data) and not the specification itself. Doing the request manual and pushing the result into ember-data's store seems to a good approach to work around that limitation.

Comment: Thanks all, @jelhan, that's what I did end up doing.

Comment: @jelhan any chance you can turn your comments into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Ember Data expects that the API returns a record with the same ID as used to find the record. If you are doing a `store.findRecord('user', 'current')` it expect that the API returns a resource with the ID `'current'`. It does not support such aliases as you are using it. Instead it will throw the assertion mentioned in your posting.

As far as I know this is *not* a limitation of the JSON:API specification. The specification is agnostic about the URL structure. It only sets some high-level rules:

> **Fetching Resources**
>
> A server MUST support fetching resource data for every URL provided as:
>
> - a self link as part of the top-level links object
> - a self link as part of a resource-level links object
> - a related link as part of a relationship-level links object
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-resources

As far as I read that it does not prevent the server from returning resource data from other URLs as well.

The specification contains a requirement about URLs for updating a resource, which you should be aware of:

> **Updating Resources**
>
> A resource can be updated by sending a PATCH request to the URL that represents the resource.
>
> The URL for a resource can be obtained in the self link of the resource object. Alternatively, when a GET request returns a single resource object as primary data, the same request URL can be used for updates.
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating

The same is true for deleting a resource:

> **Deleting Resources**
>
> An individual resource can be deleted by making a DELETE request to the resource’s URL:
>
> https://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-deleting

If you don't want to support creating and deleting resources through the alias as well you *must* include a `self` link for the resource.

In order to work-a-round the limitation of Ember Data I would recommend to do a good old `fetch` request and push the result into Ember Data's store manually using the [`store.pushPayload()`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/release/classes/Store/methods/pushPayload?anchor=pushPayload) API.